# Can't delete symbolic links, permission denied

Tags: osx, symlink, rm

I try to delete all symbolic links pointing to Python3.2 with

```
sudo ls -l . | grep '../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2' | awk '{print $9}' | xargs rm
```

This just gives

```
rm: 2to3: Permission denied
rm: 2to3-3.2: Permission denied
rm: idle3: Permission denied
rm: idle3.2: Permission denied
rm: pydoc3: Permission denied
rm: pydoc3.2: Permission denied
rm: python3: Permission denied
rm: python3-32: Permission denied
rm: python3-config: Permission denied
rm: python3.2: Permission denied
rm: python3.2-32: Permission denied
rm: python3.2-config: Permission denied
rm: python3.2m: Permission denied
rm: python3.2m-config: Permission denied
rm: pythonw3: Permission denied
rm: pythonw3-32: Permission denied
rm: pythonw3.2: Permission denied
rm: pythonw3.2-32: Permission denied
```

What gives?

Ps. there are similar threads, but there the answer/solution is that the asker did not use sudo.

Comment: Actually you also do not use `sudo` (at least not in the sense you think :)). Try your line with `... xargs sudo rm`

Comment: @qbi Ah, I think I even understand why. Thanks. Post it as an answer and I will accept it. Might be more newbs wondering about the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you also do not use `sudo` (at least not in the sense you think): only the `ls` command is run under `sudo`, then the output of `sudo ls -l .` goes through the pipe. Try your line with:

```
\ls -l . | grep '../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2' | awk '{print $9}' | sudo xargs rm
```

(`\ls` nullifies any alias that you may have for `ls`, which may cause the output format to change.)

Comment: Note that `ls` mangles some special characters and `xargs` expects input quoted in a peculiar way, so this command only works if the file names involved do not contain any special characters. Also, it doesn't work with user names containing spaces, which is possible on OSX IIRC.

Comment: It's better not to parse `ls`: [Greg's wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).